# error in definition of set in Acceleo

Tags: set, acceleo

I have a problem with definition of Set or variable.

### In the following code:

```
[template public generateElement(d : DangerClass){ a:Set(AgentClass)=Set{};}]
[comment @main/]
[file (d.name + '.java', false, 'UTF-8')]
[for (h:Hazard | d.ownedHazard)]
[for (e:Element | h.entity) ]
[if (e.oclIsKindOf(AgentClass)) {a->including(e);}][/if]
[/for]
[/for]
[/file]
[/template]
```

---

the error ". expected instead of {" is shown.(Line 6)
If I write "[for (e:Element | h.entity) {a->including(e);}]" the error "variable a->including(e); is not valid" will be displayed.
I want to define a set ("a" as Set(AgentClass)) that "a" includes agents and I don`t want to print something.But I want to store agents in a set.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to store agent in a set (no atomic display), you can use `let` to define a variable that you can use in your further expressions:

```
[template public generateElement(d : DangerClass)]
[comment @main/]
[file (d.name + '.java', false, 'UTF-8')]
[let a : Set(AgentClass) = d.ownedHazard.entity->filter(AgentClass)->asSet()]
  ... handle 'a' in your future requests
[/let]
[/file]
[/template]
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are immutable in acceleo and OCL.

Just do this, for instance:

```
[for (agentClass : AgentClass | d.ownedHazard.entity->filter(AgentClass))]
  (... here, generate something with agentClass ...)
[/for]
```